# Why didn't God kill Cain?

Tags: murder, genesis-bereishith

Why didn't God kill Cain for murdering his brother Abel? God punished Er and Onan for wasting seeds, which is seen in Judaism as akin to murder, the nature of Cain's crime was the same and he was spared. Is there a reason for this? Is there a bigger reason?

Comment: Note: Cain did die prematurely, so not sure if this is even a question? But yeah, would love to know the "bigger" reason myself. Hopefully someone will provide a good answer

Comment: Could it be that there was a fear of Adam and Eve not having more children and humanity having a premature end because after that there was a large gap of time until Seth was born. But with that we would put in check the omniscience of God I presume.

Comment: Another question could also be asked regarding anyone else who killed someone throughout history, why Hashem didn't kill them immediately

Comment: It's the same with Jews who say that the waste of seed is still valid for Gentiles, so why doesn't God kill every man who practices masturbation today like he did with Onan? Or even Jews, we don't see mass deaths of people in the bathroom. lol. Some higher explanation must exist, let's look for it.

Answer (score 2):

Chizkuni on Genesis 4:15 (1) implies that Cain did some form of teshuva. In (5) he mentions that mankind had not yet been warned about the sin murder. Both of these are potential answers.

Ibn Ezra says that Hashem, in this verse, is implying that *Cain* is the subject -

> The meaning of our verse is that God held back his anger and waited seven generations before punishing Cain (the verse is to be understood as follows: Cain shall be punished after seven generations.)

Radak says:

> According to Torah Shleymah on our chapter item #114 G’d told Kayin that in consideration of the fact that he now displayed fear of and reverence for G’d, he would have his lifespan extended for seven generations. Onkelos explains the expression שבעתים as receiving punishment spread over seven generations. Just as Kayin’s eventual death was suspended for 7 generations, so he who killed him would experience a similar fate. Eventually, Lemech killed Kayin.

Rashi and Siftei Chachamim also bring this idea. I didn't find any sources to corroborate the issue of there being no further children to Adam and Eve. As you said, the omnipotence of Hashem would preclude that (but there is a question of Hashem being kind to Adam and Eve and not leaving them childless)

Comment: Interestingly in the Midrash Adam asks Cain what Hashem told him after he sinned , and after Cain replied that once he did teshuva, Hashem spared him, Adam got so inspired by the idea of teshuva that he did teshuva for the sin of the tree of knowledge

Comment: Lamech killed Cain? The text in Genesis doesn't seem to indicate that, Lamch proclaimed that Cain would be punished even before him, so he was alive. What you can understand is God doing with Cain the same as he did with Adam and Eve, he will die but not in his time but in mine, they say that one day for God is equal to 1000 years for us, Adam gave 70 years to David and died aged 930, this I heard from a Hasidic rabbi. Now in other cases like Onan it seems to require a greater reflection that I simply don't have.